# Vuex. Boa pratica ao utilizar o Mutation

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Tenho uma duvida quanto atualizar o state usando o `mutation`, geralmente vejo a utilização da seguinte maneira:

```
[ALGUM_MUTATION_TYPE] (state, novoArray) {
   state.array = novoArray
}
```

Nesse modelo, sobrescrevemos os dados do `state.array` gerando um novo conteúdo.

**Minha duvida são:**

- Se precisar adicionar somente um item neste array, é preciso fazer como no modo acima sobrescrevendo tudo?
- Não podemos simplesmente dar um push?
- Não teria uma melhor performance?

Dessa maneira:

```
[ALGUM_MUTATION_TYPE] (state, item) {
   state.array.push(item)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Se precisar adicionar somente um item neste `array`, é preciso fazer como no modo acima sobrescrevendo tudo?

Depende como está sendo enviado a nova atualização do seu estado, se estiver enviando todos os itens do `array` precisa salvar todos e se estiver enviando somente a posição nova então um `push`:

```
state.array.push(item);
```

ou como é visto e feito por muitos assim:

```
state.array = [...state.array, item]; // ou state.array = newItems;
```

faz a adição ou alteração de todos os items.

As duas formas estão corretas não tem nesse aspecto comparação de desempenho e na minha opinião a segunda é realmente a cópia do novo valor com todos os itens. No caso exemplo no `Vue` isso funciona (`push` ou cópia completa) em outras como por exemplo `React` somente dar um `push` não resolve precisa copiar o novo `array` e enviar, então, a segunda forma é mais compatível e usual pela maioria, não acho que é moda mas, sim a forma correta de mudar o estado.

Um exemplo funcional:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {    
    items: []
  },
  mutations: {   
    addItem(state, value) {
      state.items = [...state.items, value]; // correto
      //state.items.push(value); // também correto
    }
  },
  actions: {
    addItem(context, value) {
      context.commit("addItem", value);
    }
  }
});
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  data: {
    value: ''
  },
  computed: {   
    items() {
      return this.$store.state.items;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleAddItem: function() {
      if (this.value) {
        this.$store.dispatch("addItem", this.value);
      } else {
        alert("Digite o item!");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.1.2/vuex.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
      <p>
        <input type="text" v-model="value" />
        <button v-on:click="handleAddItem">Add Item</button>
      </p>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(item,index) in items" v-bind:key="index">{{item}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

<sup>***Referencias***</sup>

- [O que é Vuex?](https://vuex.vuejs.org/ptbr/)
- [Installation - Vue](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html)
- [Vue CLI ️ Standard Tooling for Vue.js Development](https://cli.vuejs.org/)

Comment: Excelente resposta Man! Muito obrigado!  
Então acredito que seja possível utilizar o push/unshift normalmente no state e ainda manter a reatividade.

Comment: No caso do `Vue` eu acredito que dá, mas, como não existe um padrão no `React` por exemplo não dá! @RubensBarbosa.